# An upper bound on a sequence of positive numbers $x_n$ such that $x_{n+1} \le \min \{b \cdot x_n,c\}$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

Suppose $\{x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_n,\ldots \}$ is a sequence that satisfies $x_0 = a$, and $x_{n+1} \le \min \{b \cdot x_n,c\}$, where $a,b,c>0$ are constant given numbers, and $x_i>0$ for $i=0,1,2,\ldots$

Now, I want to find an upper bound for $x_n$ as tight as possible.

---

My current solution is the following:

Since $x_{n+1} \le \min \{b \cdot x_n,c\}$ implies that

$$x_{n+1} \le b \cdot x_n  \tag 1$$

$$x_{n+1} \le c  \tag2$$

From (1), we can get,

$$x_{n} \le b^n \cdot a   \tag3$$

Combining (3) with (2) yields

$$x_{n} \le \min \{c,b^n \cdot a  \}$$

However, I am not sure if there are some other ways to find another upper bound that is less tight than the above one. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: It seems odd to have an upper bound for $x_n$ contain $n$ itself in the formula. Also it might be good to consider cases on $b$ e.g. if $b<1$ the $x_n$ tend to get small, while if $b>1$ they can grow, but will eventually encounter the other bound $c$ and have to stay below that. Maybe some details of how this is of use would help someone give a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your bound is a reasonable one, given the strange assumptions on $x_{n+1}$. One more thing that could be done is to consider that when $c<a$ and $b<1$, we get $x_1\le \min(ab,c)$ and subsequently $$x_n \le \min(ab^n , cb^{n-1}, c)\tag1$$ Since the sequence $$a,\ \min(ab,c),\ \min(ab^2 , cb^{1}, c),\ \min(ab^3, cb^{2}, c),\dots$$
satisfies the given constraints, the bound (1) cannot be improved.